# Multi-lingual app vs many apps

Tags: iphone, ios, internationalization, app-store

**Problem:** I'm making game app for iPhone. I have already this app in App Store (in my language - polish), but I'm working on german and english versions. This app has loads of images/sounds language dependent. If it was only strings, this would be easy, but images/sounds wiegth much more...

The way I see it I have two options:
1) update app in App Store with localized content - but it will make at the end my app 2-3 times bigger. I don't think that people will be so eager to download a 60mb app instead of 15mb...
2) make 3 apps with the same(?) name, but different content for each language - I'm not sure App Store will accept this method, but app will be lighter

**Question:** Does anybody know how to solve such a problem? Option 1 or 2? Or maybe something else is to do?

Answer (score 2):

You could download your language files (Sound, Images, etc.) when your app launches the first time for the current language.
And if the user changes his language, you can redownload all images and sounds for the new language and store them both on the device.

Comment: If carefully designed, this solution has another advantage: you can add new languages to the game without even redistributing a new version. Just update your list of languages on the server, and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer option #1. When I'm downloading a game, it doesn't bother me whether the game is 15 MB or 60 MB.

As for option #2, I'm not sure whether you can create several apps with the same name.

And generally the users shouldn't be concerned about which version they are downloading.
That really is the tipping point from my objective. Let the users choose the language with-in the app.

Maybe you should look into if your images and sounds could be compressed further?

I'm not that much into game development, but it's just my 50 cents.

Comment: In my opinion, size does matter. If you are on the go, 15 MB or 60 MB is a huge difference.

Comment: Yeah, I get your point. But still, with WiFi everywhere and flat-rate 3G connections...

Comment: flate rate 3g is rare in europe. Most plans do have a 200mb/300mb limit. after that you download with 6 kb/s

Comment: I wouldn't know anything about that, and that's why I get your point. Where I'm living it's not unusual with plans with several GB's. So I see the problem if we're down to a couple of hundred MB's and no WiFi in range.